# FieldInfo.GetRawConstantValue is not avaliable on UWP

Tags: c#, reflection, uwp, constants, class-constants

I need to get a value of a constant inside my class.
`GetField` works fine.

But then `myFieldInfo.GetRawConstantValue()` normally works perfectly, but is not available on UWP.

Is there any way to achieve this on UWP?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to achieve this on UWP?

Derive from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getrawconstantvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2#applies-to). `GetRawConstantValue` method apply to `.NET Standard`. So you could create `.NET Standard` class library that could referenced by UWP project.

```
public class LibCore
{
    public static object GetRawConstantValue(Type target, string filedName)
    {
        var filed = target.GetField(filedName);
        var value = filed.GetRawConstantValue();
        return value;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var value = LibCore.GetRawConstantValue(typeof(Person), "Name");
```

Note:
If version of `.NET Standard` class library  is 2.0, you need modify uwp min version to 16299.